# How to get equivalent of Vim's :Texplore in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I know about M-x dire, but would like to customize it. I would like to hit one key (for example F2) and get dire buffer open. When I navigate across the directory hierarchy it shouldn't open new buffers.

And when I finally open the file it also shouldn't open new buffer for it (not strictly necessary, but strongly preferred).

Of course this behavior can be global, i.e. for all dire buffers/invocations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I finally used:

```
(require 'dired)
(global-set-key [(f2)] 'my-dired)
(defun my-dired ()
  (interactive)
  (dired (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))))
(defadvice dired-advertised-find-file (around dired-subst-directory activate)
  "Replace current buffer if file is a directory."
  (interactive)
  (let ((orig (current-buffer)) (filename (dired-get-filename :no-error-if-not-filep t)))
  ad-do-it
  (when (not (eq (current-buffer) orig)) (kill-buffer orig))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out [dired-single](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dired-single.el), which pretty much does what you want (except that last bit, where it reuses the dired buffer for the newly visted file).

Caveat Lector: I wrote it, so I'm biased towards its usefulness.

Comment: No bias here, and I think dired-single.el is awesome. I've been using it for a while and it's exactly what I needed when I first looked it up.

(No idea how it compares to :Texplore since I've never really used vim.)

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives - [EmacsWiki: DiredReuseDirectoryBuffer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredReuseDirectoryBuffer), and [this short snippet](http://avizit.blogspot.com/2004/10/dired-to-open-new-directories-in-same.html) from an awkwardly-formatted blog-entry.

caveat: haven't tried them, myself.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old but All you have to do is press 'a' on a dir or file to get this functionality. It's already there.